# Json assertion with condition

Tags: jmeter

I have a json key 'total' in api response, which will return values on condition. Need to assert if response value is >= 0 and 0. Please suggest a simple way to achieve this.

I have already tried Json assertion which is not of much help.

I expect 'total' to contain a value greater than 0 (zero) at certain time and 0 (zero) at certain time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below regEx to fetch the values:=

```
total=\d+
```

Put it in Regular Expression Extractor postprocessor.

It will fetch only 0 or any positive number else not found. Now, put if controller to work further with your scenerio.

Hope this helps.

**Update:-** Put assertion to check if the response contain the required parameter,if yes it will pass else fail. So, if negative then it will fail.
In this, you dont need to put regular expression extractor as you can put expected regEx directly in response assertion.

[image]

Comment: can you help me with if controller? how to fail test if condition are not met.

Comment: Please check the update if it helps with you scenario.

Comment: snippet of response data looks like this : "LastPaymentAmount":0,"PastDue":0,"Total":194.86,"TotalDepositAmount":0.

Comment: should I include the " and : in the patterns?

Comment: Yes..like this  --->"PastDue":(\d+),

Comment: I need almost the same but I want it to fail if total=0